# executereader commandtext property has not been initialized c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

this is a piece of code which is showing exception. It take sql query entered in text from textbox on the Window form (testform) and display the result in excel sheet. how can i take value in string to so that it dont show exception and that sql1 is textbox name is empty function in Testform.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Exceloutput_Application;

public class ProcessDataset
{
    public ProcessDataset()
    {

    }

    public static DataTable ReadTable()
    {
        TestForm t = new TestForm();
        var returnValue = new DataTable();
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString._connectionString);
        string st = t.sql1.Text;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand(st, conn);
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(returnValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception details as well.

Comment: It point at throw ex and give the exception that InvalidOperationException was unhandled in amessage box. below that it is ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized

Comment: You are never showing your TestForm to your users.  Your `st` variable is likely an empty string.

Comment: Also,  use `throw` instead of `throw ex` to keep the original stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for comment .. Can u please provide the way it can be done. TestForm.cs is different file that is a form which have textbox (sql1) and button (create) . Can u please help in code

Comment: Exception details please. Also wrap a using around your con object instead of manually closing it.

Comment: You want, var myform = new TestForm(); myform.Show();

Comment: The exception I am getting is "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll." The change is still not working. All other things are running well. Just that it is not showing textbox content in string of sql connect. Please help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

You either assume that instantiating (new) a `Form` magically shows it or gets a reference to an existing open form. None of those assumptions is true.

To show a form to the user you either call [`Application.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx) for your first form (the main form of your application) or [`Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)
 or [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) on a instance you created.

Let me add comments to the first few lines of your `ReadTable` method:

```
TestForm t = new TestForm(); // this ONLY creates a NEW form in memory
// if you were looking at a TestForm already t holds a new form
// and not the one you're looking at.
var returnValue = new DataTable();
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString._connectionString);
// the form is not shown to the user at this point
// and never will be because YOU didn't tell it to Show
// The textbox is empty
string st = t.sql1.Text;
// st will be an empty string here
```

With that explained let's see possible solutions. You might be tempted to add

```
t.Show();
```

directly after you created the TestForm. That does show the form but Show is non-blocking. Which means it will continue immediately with the rest of the code still leading to an empty result in `st`.

```
t.ShowDialog();
```

will enable you to see the form and fill in any values.  `ShowDialog` will block until the users closes the form or you have a button that calls `Close` or `Hide` in the click event.

Based on the sparse information you provided I assume you already have `TestForm` open, with a button on it that calls `ReadTable`. If you change `ReadTable` to accept a the sql string, you don't have to juggle with the forms. 
Something like this will do:

```
public class ProcessDataset
{
    // Takes a Sql string
    public static DataTable ReadTable(string sql)
    {
       var returnValue = new DataTable();
       // checks if there is a sql string provided
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sql)) 
       {

            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString._connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            // rest of code
       }
       else 
       {
           // show message to user
           MessageBox.Show(" no sql command ");
       }
       return returnValue;
    }
 }
```

And you will call it from your click event like so:

```
private  void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var resultset = ProcessDataset.ReadTable(sql1.Text);
}
```

**tl;dr** There is not much wrong with your SqlCommand code. You simply failed in getting the correct reference to your Textbox that contains some sql statement. Calling sqlcommand with an empty string raises the exception you are seeing.